# Using a JScrollPane in a JEditorPane

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

Hi so I'm struggling to apply a JScrollPanel within a JEditorPane.
I have a main content window (which has a scroll bar) and within that a JEditorPane that I would like to scroll slide horizontal and vertical. So far I have

```
JEditorPane monApp = new JEditorPane();
```

and have tried

```
ScrollablePanel panel = new ScrollablePanel();
panel.setScrollableWidth( ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT );
```

along with a few other things but couldn't seem to get any of them working.

Comment: Have you embedded the editor in the scrollpane? See [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details